# jquery file loading multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery file (jquery-1.11.3.min.js) loading multiple (4) times. I think i know it is because of the below jquery files in index.html page too. The thing i don't know is how to stop it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

[image]

[image]

I just created a demo page like below in VS and i can see 4 instances of jquery-1.11.3.min.js in VS Solution Window.
I think the issue is just with Visual Studio and it seems the browser's developer tools are showing just 1 instance of jquery-1.xx.js file. 
Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="G5 - KA/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="G5 - KA/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="G5 - KA/css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="G5 - KA/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="G5 - KA/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="G5 - KA/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is just jquery test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of those is loading jQuery v1.11.3 at all.

Comment: We're going to need to see more of your page. Hit it on a browser and view-source to make sure you see what the browser is actually processing.

Comment: Add `jquery` before these three and make sure you use compatible versions.

Comment: I just attached some screenshots and I did view source and it is what it looks in the attached image in description. And i also searched the whole code and it has just 1 instance of 'jquery-1.11.3.min.js'.

Comment: Fiddle or other demo page so we can see?

Answer (score -1):

This is best way.

// Only do anything if jQuery isn't defined

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
if (typeof $ == 'function') {
    // warning, global var
    thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary = true;
}

function getScript(url, success) {

    var script     = document.createElement('script');
         script.src = url;

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    done = false;

    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {

        done = true;

            // callback function provided as param
            success();

            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            head.removeChild(script);

        };

    };

    head.appendChild(script);

};

getScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', function() {

    if (typeof jQuery=='undefined') {

        // Super failsafe - still somehow failed...

    } else {

        // jQuery loaded! Make sure to use .noConflict just in case
        fancyCode();

        if (thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary) {

            // Run your jQuery Code

        } else {

            // Use .noConflict(), then run your jQuery Code

        }

    }

});

} else { // jQuery was already loaded

// Run your jQuery Code

};
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why OPs jQuery is loading 4 times. You should have to use JS to load jQuery.

Comment: @putvande use Fiddle We're going to need to see more of your page.